# Is there a way to setup mixed covariance in flow generics?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm using `// @flow strict` and the use of `*` and `any` are banned.

I'd like to create an array of functions having variable return types, but still use those functions in a strict fashion.

[Here's an example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHdQGcAuAnAlgYxQKFygJ4AOApqAMqgC8oA3gD66igDUSsAtqQHICunAEak0ALlAA7AcLQAaZmw7cK6DBIDm41Jg24GAXwDc+ImUqlopHLDQAeACoA+GqAAUqAIYpS4igEoaZ3tjfBBQewALDCRQDzQ0D0JJUlIAExiUWFAI2GhU0Eg+CRwMWAkMiK9QNFIUPjQJUFSMSEgRUgkUatIkPmgUJAA6XDCeWC6PaDh4NNBM0D4kcgAqUBtYiUJcLDLUZAsrTLQkcQBBeMTbCgPrO04MAA80x2daAG0AXWMWBRGwSOiBSKJTKsSmCAq5FwhWKKFKjSWlhwtgAmo53Dcjr5MTZUY4-OIUfQFDtyl0kB5OMRLAB5QQAK18LjoChYSl40hE4gAjAAmADM8hYbK4pBUOk0oAA5AAWACsADYpULQEZfmyccdBsRFhEMUijn5DKAwrYALRm7IIOZZTgeADW5BQURi8Bs9oA-ABCdXdOoNfYGmzuSnU0h0+lG3D6X5hABKtXqjVM5EBaja8VmgiSzvIiMOs2IaFgZDQRGGpL2uf4QhELnzOHcgWQg3ZNZkUcrXVz4rU6nrmKb1GcQ3ZvY0UaAA)

I need to store the functions with a `mixed` return type. I tried covariance, but I'm not sure how that works in flow. Is there a way to fix the error in this example without hiding the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to push into that array, you need to [mark `Selector`'s template argument as covariant](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-variance-sigils). You can change

```
type Selector<T> = (state: S) => T;
```

to be

```
type Selector<+T> = (state: S) => T;
```

As you can see the `<T>` is now `<+T>`, so that you can safely convert from `Y` to `mixed`.

Comment: So simple. I was using the `+` in the wrong place. Thanks!